# The indicators of two measurable sets times $f$ is measurable if and only if the indicator of the union times $f$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I want to prove:

Let $A$ and $B$ be measurable subsets of $\mathbf{R}$. Let $S = A \cup B$ and $f: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$. Then the function $1_S f$ is measurable if and only if the functions $1_A f$ and $1_B f$ are measurable. $1_X$ means indicator function, and $f^{-1}(X)$ means preimage set.

My attempt at solution:

Assume that $1_S f$ is measurable. For any set $E \subset \mathbf{R}$ we have 
\begin{align*}
(1_S f)^{-1}(E) \cap A = \{x \in \mathbf{R} : 1_S f(x) \in E \text{ and } x \in A \}  = \{x \in \mathbf{R} : 1_A f(x) \in E \} = (1_A f)^{-1} (E).
\end{align*}
Similarly, $(1_S f)^{-1}(E) \cap B = (1_B f)^{-1} (E)$. If $E$ is measurable, then $(1_S f)^{-1}(E)$ is measurable, and the intersection of two measurable sets is measurable, which implies $(1_Af)^{-1}(E)$ and $(1_B f)^{-1}(E)$ are measurable, so we are done.

For the second direction, assume that $1_Af$ and $1_Bf$ are measurable. For any $E \subset \mathbf{R}$ we have 
\begin{align*}
(1_A f)^{-1}(E) \cup (1_B f)^{-1}(E) = (f^{-1}(E) \cap A) \cup (f^{-1}(E) \cap B) = f^{-1}(E) \cap (A \cup B) = f^{-1}(E) \cap S = (1_S f)^{-1} (E),
\end{align*}
so for $E$ measurable we get $(1_S f)^{-1}(E)$ measurable since its equal to the union of two measurable sets.

Do you see any flaws with this proof? Also, I will upvote and accept alternative proofs as well.

Comment: I will look at this.  Though, an alternative approach is to write $1_S f$ in terms of measurable functions, and similar for the other direction (write $1_Af$ in terms of measurable functions).

Comment: Your approach looks good.  The first part could be interpreted as $1_A f = (1_A) (1_S f)$, which is what I was alluding to in my above comment.

Comment: Thanks. How would one write $1_S f$ in terms of measurable functions? As the limit of a sequence?

Comment: You could use $A^c$ is measurable.

Comment: I do not see what this leads to. I tried writing $1_S f$ in terms of measurable functions already by using $S = (A - (A \cap B)) \cup (A \cap B) \cup (B - (A \cap B))$, but this didn't seem useful.

Comment: What about $S = A \cup (A^c \cap B)$.

Comment: With that information, we can write $1_Sf = 1_A f + 1_{A^c \cap B} f$. Also, $1_B f$ measurable implies $1_{A^c \cap B} f = (1_{B} f) (1_{B \cap A^c})$ is measurable. Then the sum of two measurable functions is measurable, which gives us one direction. What about if we start with $1_S f$ is measurable?

Comment: Or just $1_S f = 1_Af + (1_{A^c})(1_B f)$.  The other direction seems to be from my second comment.